# Jquery change event in Datalist[html5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

this is my code:

```
<input name="cmbname" type="text" id="cmbname" list="listcmbname" autocomplete="off" runat="server">
<datalist id="listcmbname">
         <option data-id="1" value="a"></option>
         <option data-id="8" value="aa"></option>
         <option data-id="10" value="aaa"></option>
         <option data-id="11" value="b"></option>
         <option data-id="15" value="bb"></option>
         <option data-id="18" value="bbb"></option>
</datalist>
```

I used `cmbname.value` to get input value in the code behind.
But I also need the data-id. I've used `cmbname.Attributes["data-id"]` but it did not work.
I think it will be fixed with jquery change event.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/xttwt/48/,

you can find out the data-id of option currently selected like this:

```
var val=$('#cmbname').val();
var data_id= $('#listcmbProcess').find('option[value="'+val+'"]').data('id');
```

Comment: I was followed this. Thank you very much.
In the code behind I have used `cmbname.Attributes["data-id"]` but it returns null.

Comment: @nimashayanfar.. it will only return the value if the text inside the input matches to any of options in datalist

Comment: see this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n8faLs4j/), I used it of your code and use `cmbname.Attributes["data-id"]` in the asp.net code behind , but returned null.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Jquery has the [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/). So to get the 'data-id' attribute, you would use `$('input').data("id");`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#cmbname').attr('data-id');` you can also use this to get the data id

Answer (score 0):

Use this [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#cmbname').attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this:

```
<input id="cmbLoc" name="cmbLoc" runat="server" list="listcmbLoc" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="listcmbLoc">
       <option data-id="15" value="CPF"></option>
       <option data-id="18" value="HOLD"></option>
       <option data-id="19" value="CCR"></option>
 </datalist>
<div style="display: none"><input id="cmbLoc_ID" type="text" name="cmbLoc_ID" runat="server"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#cmbLoc").change(function () {
$("#MainContent_cmbLoc_ID").val($('#listcmbLoc').find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('id'));
          });
    });
</script>
```

And enter `cmbLoc_ID.value` in the code behind it to get `data-id`.